# Server routing and vtun on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, routing

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 LTE virtual server, kernel 2.6.32, and a VPN with vtun running.

In the VPN, the server is 6.6.6.6, and the two clients are 6.6.6.29 and 6.6.6.35.

If I ping 6.6.6.6 from any client, the server responds immediately. So I believe clients are configured correctly. BUT if I ping 6.6.6.35 from 6.6.6.29, or viceversa, there's no response.

A traceroute from 6.6.6.29 says:

$ traceroute -n 6.6.6.35

```
traceroute to 6.6.6.35 (6.6.6.35), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  6.6.6.6  78.409 ms  80.202 ms  82.820 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
```

I guess there is a routing problem in the routing tables of the server.

My config files are:

$ cat /etc/default/vtun

```
RUN_SERVER=yes
```

$ cat /etc/vtund.conf

```
options {
    bindaddr {
        addr 85.84.83.82;
    };
}

default {
    type      tun;
    proto     tcp;
    persist   yes;
    keepalive yes;
    stat      yes;
    multi     yes;
}

client1 {
    passwd   U'dLikeToKnow;

    up {
        ifconfig "%% 6.6.6.6 pointopoint 6.6.6.29 mtu 1450";
        route "add -net 6.6.6.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 6.6.6.29";
    };
    down {
        ifconfig "%% down";
        route "del -net 6.6.6.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 6.6.6.29";
    };
}

client2 {
    passwd   U'dLikeToKnow;

    up {  
        ifconfig "%% 6.6.6.6 pointopoint 6.6.6.35 mtu 1450";
        route "add -net 6.6.6.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 6.6.6.35";
    };
    down {
        ifconfig "%% down";
        route "del -net 6.6.6.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 6.6.6.35";
    };
}
```

$ ifconfig

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  direcciónHW 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          Direc. inet:6.6.6.6  P-t-P:6.6.6.29  Másc:255.255.255.255
          ACTIVO PUNTO A PUNTO FUNCIONANDO NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1450  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:358 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:18 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:500 
          Bytes RX:27624 (27.6 KB)  TX bytes:1560 (1.5 KB)

tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  direcciónHW 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          Direc. inet:6.6.6.6  P-t-P:6.6.6.35  Másc:255.255.255.255
          ACTIVO PUNTO A PUNTO FUNCIONANDO NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1450  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:98 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:91 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:500 
          Bytes RX:10580 (10.5 KB)  TX bytes:8579 (8.5 KB)
```

$ route

```
Tabla de rutas IP del núcleo
Destino         Pasarela        Genmask         Indic Métric Ref    Uso Interfaz
6.6.6.29        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
6.6.6.35        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
6.6.6.0         6.6.6.35        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun1
6.6.6.0         6.6.6.29        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 venet0
```

But the MOST strange thing is that this problem appeared when I upgraded the server from version 10.04 LTE to 12.04 LTE.

How can I rapair the routing table?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I add: sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward is set to 1